# Fetch limited fields in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cakephp

I am having trouble fetching limited fields in cakephp.

Following is the find query:

```
$payment = $this -> Payment -> find('first', array('recursive' => 2));
```

On debugging, I get following output.

```
[Pricing] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [plan_id] => 1
        [price] => 150
        [Plan] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [course] => One
                [course_name] => OnePlus
                [description] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text
                [discount] => 0

            )

    )
```

But from `Plan` array I only need to get `course_name`. So I tried:

```
$payment = $this -> Payment -> find('first', array('recursive' => 2, 
                              'fields' => array(
                                          'Pricing.Plan.course_name'
                                          )
                               ));
```

But I get error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Pricing.Plan.course_name' in 'field list'`

Kindly help me get only `couse_name` field from `Plan` array.

Comment: Try to avoid recursive at all costs in 2.x. Instead, use "contain".

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
 $payment = $this -> Payment -> find('first', array('recursive' => 2, 
                          'fields' => array(
                                      'Plan.course_name'
                                      )
                           ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$payment = $this->Payment->find('first', array('recursive' => 2, 
                          'fields' => array(
                                      'Pricing.*','Plan.course_name'
                                      )
                           ));
```